# Devise in namespace - ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"})

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise and everything has been working great, but I am now trying to move things into an 'admin' namespace.

I have a route that looks like:

```
namespace :admin do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "admin/users/registrations" }
end
```

In one of my controllers I have

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

but when that gets called it throws:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}):
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How does your RegistrationsController look like?

Answer (score 3):

As per the Devise documentation (which likely has changed since this posting), you could use the following instructions:

```
#    ...
#    
#    Notice that whenever you use namespace in the router DSL, it automatically sets the module.
#    So the following setup:
#
#      namespace :publisher do
#        devise_for :account
#      end
#
#    Will use publisher/sessions controller instead of devise/sessions controller. You can revert
#    this by providing the :module option to devise_for.
#    
#    ...
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this:

```
scope '/admin' do
  devise_for :admins
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this is to use the `path` option and move `devise_for` **outside** of the `namespace` block:

```
devise_for :users, :path => '/admin',
                   :controllers => { :registrations => "admin/users/registrations" }
namespace :admin do
  # other resource controllers
end
```

Perhaps it's not as elegant (or intuitive), but it works for me!